# Eliminate the msg "The action cannot he completed because the file is open in ServiceHub.Host.x86"?

Tags: visual-studio

I have commonly copied a folder / contents and added a date to that copy name.

With VS2019, I see "The action can't he completed because the file is open in ServiceHub.Host.x86".

How do I get rid of this message?  (I don't want to go back close the project, copy the folder / contents, then re-open it.)  I don't use Service Hub (whatever that is)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quote from a VS agent:

"I test in my side with different kinds of solution/projects and I find that it seems when I use C++ Console Application, it will work and successfully copy and paste/modify. But when I use C# Console Application the dialog window stops me."

"I strongly recommend you to report this condition to product team for further improving or maybe suggest a feature to add an option to disable this auto-locking feature."

"Help -> Send Feedback -> Report a Problem… is appropriate."